# Prove that every ideal of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $M_n(R)$ be the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $R$. Prove that every ideal of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

The following is my solution (a hint was available with the problem):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an ideal of $M_n(R)$ and let $$I=\{a\in R: a\  \text{is an entry of some matrix in}\ \mathcal{M}\}.$$

Then $\mathcal{M}\subseteq M_n(I)$ because $A\in \mathcal{M}$ implies that entries of $A$ belong to $I$.

Next we need to show that $I$ is an ideal. To that end let $a,b\in I.$ Suppose $a$ is the $rs$th entry of some matrix $A$ in $\mathcal{M}$. Then we have

$$
\bbox[yellow]
{F_{ij}(a)=F_{ir}(1_R)AF_{sj}(1_R)\in\mathcal{M};\ 1\leq i,j\leq n,}
$$

where $F_{ij}(a)$ denotes the matrix in $M_n(R)$ with $a$ as its $ij$th entry and zeroes elsewhere. So $F_{11}(a),F_{11}(b)\in\mathcal{M}.$ Since $\mathcal{M}$ is an ideal we have $F_{11}(a-b)=F_{11}(a)-F_{11}(b)\in\mathcal{M}$ or rather $a-b\in I.$ Next let $r\in R, x\in I$. Then $$F_{11}(rx)=F_{11}(r)F_{11}(x)\in \mathcal{M},\ F_{11}(xr)=F_{11}(x)F_{11}(r)\in\mathcal{M}.$$ Therefore $xr, rx\in I$. Hence $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Finally we need to show that $M_n(I)\subseteq \mathcal{M}$. Suppose $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(I).$ Then each entry of $A$ is an entry of some matrix in $\mathcal{M}$. So $F_{ij}(a_{ij})\in\mathcal{M};\ 1\leq i,j\leq n.$ So $$A=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n F_{ij}(a_{ij})\in\mathcal{M}.$$ Therefore $M_n(I)\subseteq \mathcal{M}$. Hence $\mathcal{M}=M_n(I)$.

Is the above argument correct? The hint given was the highlighted part and I cannot see how that part is true. Could someone please help me figure out how? Thanks.

---

**PS**: I saw this problem has already been posted on this site but the purpose of my post is to ascertain the validity of my proof and clarify the aforementioned part.

Comment: That $I$ is an ideal was in the hint. I've tried showing that it is in fact an ideal. Is the argument flawed?

Comment: Your argument, as far as I can tell, is alright. Regading your highlighted formula, note that $AF_{sj}(1)$ throws out all of the columns of $A$ (equates to zero), except for the $j$th column. Similarly $F_{ir}(1)A$ filters the $i$th row. Combining them you are left with the $ij$th entry.

Comment: How is the product in $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{M} = M_n(R)\,\mathcal{M}\,M_n(R)$ that's part of the definition of **two-sided** ideals of $M_n(R)$. It will fail for left-ideals. @Cauchy $I$ is clearly an ideal.